# Navigation component not merging with current codebase

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-architecture-navigation

I have an issue am stuck on reading the usage of Navigation component, dagger and databinding.

my stackTrace on the error throw is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp, PID: 16021
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp/go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.ui.signup.AuthActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36 in go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp:layout/activity_auth: Binary XML file line #36 in go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp:layout/activity_auth: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36 in go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp:layout/activity_auth: Binary XML file line #36 in go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp:layout/activity_auth: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36 in go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp:layout/activity_auth: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.viewModel.MyViewModelFactory.create(MyViewModelFactory.java:37)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.ui.signup.LandingFragment.onCreate(LandingFragment.java:34)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2571)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1685)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:264)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1818)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.java:166)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:51)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1069)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:997)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.ui.signup.AuthActivity.onCreate(AuthActivity.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.util.PreferenceManager.<init>(PreferenceManager.java:12)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.di.AppModule.providesPreferenceManager(AppModule.java:19)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.di.AppModule_ProvidesPreferenceManagerFactory.providesPreferenceManager(AppModule_ProvidesPreferenceManagerFactory.java:37)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.di.AppModule_ProvidesPreferenceManagerFactory.get(AppModule_ProvidesPreferenceManagerFactory.java:27)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.di.AppModule_ProvidesPreferenceManagerFactory.get(AppModule_ProvidesPreferenceManagerFactory.java:10)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.repository.AuthenticationRepository_Factory.get(AuthenticationRepository_Factory.java:26)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.repository.AuthenticationRepository_Factory.get(AuthenticationRepository_Factory.java:9)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.viewModel.AuthenticationViewModel_Factory.get(AuthenticationViewModel_Factory.java:22)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.viewModel.AuthenticationViewModel_Factory.get(AuthenticationViewModel_Factory.java:8)
        at go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.viewModel.MyViewModelFactory.create(MyViewModelFactory.java:35)
            ... 55 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16021 SIG: 9
```

The complain Areas are

ViewModelFactory:

```
 public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
        Provider<? extends ViewModel> creator = creators.get(modelClass);
        if (creator == null) {
            for (Map.Entry<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> entry : creators.entrySet()) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(entry.getKey())) {
                    creator = entry.getValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass);
        }
        try {
            return (T) creator.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

the Activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.viewModel.AuthenticationViewModel" />
    </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.signup.AuthActivity">
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/authentication_navigation"
        tools:ignore="FragmentTagUsage" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

the Activity

```
public class AuthActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {
@Inject
MyViewModelFactory factory;
private ActivityAuthBinding binding;
private AuthenticationViewModel viewModel;

private NavHostFragment finalHost;
private NavController navController;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_auth);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,factory).get(AuthenticationViewModel.class);
    binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
    finalHost = NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.authentication_navigation);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(binding.navHostFragment.getId(), finalHost)
            .setPrimaryNavigationFragment(finalHost) // equivalent to app:defaultNavHost="true"
            .commit();
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
}
```

}

the navigation component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/authentication_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/navigation_landing">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_landing"
        android:name="go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.ui.signup.LandingFragment"
        android:label=""
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_landing" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_landing_to_checkUSer"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_checkUser" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_landing_to_permissions_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_permission" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_checkUser"
        android:name="go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.ui.signup.CheckUserFragment"
        android:label="Input phone"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_check_user" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_checkuser_to_login_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_Login" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_checkuser_to_register_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_Register" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_Login"
        android:name="go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.ui.signup.LoginFragment"
        android:label="Input Otp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_login_to_permissions_fragment"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_permission" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_login_to_image_upload"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_image_upload" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_Register"
        android:name="go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.ui.signup.RegisterFragment"
        android:label="Register"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_newsfeed_to_newsFeedPostDetailsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_Login" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_image_upload"
        android:name="go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.ui.signup.RegisterFragment"
        android:label="Image Upload"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_upload_image" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_image_upload_to_navigation_permission"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_permission" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_permission"
        android:name="go.ke.antifgmboard.androidapp.ui.signup.PermissionsFragment"
        android:label="Grant Permission"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_permission" >
    </fragment>



</navigation>
```

My issue seems to be arising from the point at which I attach the navigation component hopefully one of you can assist also the di modules are complaining but I am sure this can all be resolved once the underlying issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try to define your `startDestination` in your `navigation.xml` file.

Also, check if you have added this:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5"
```

Comment: I have done all the above... let me add the navigation class defination

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what the issue was with my code... The worst part is that it was completely unrelated with the navigation error however the error stack trace was pinpointing as to where my problem was originating from.

The cause was an empty SharedPrefference Management class which was diving my di crazy this was the issue

```
public class PreferenceManager {
    Context context;
    String UNICEF_PREFERENCE = "UNICEF_Preference";
    SharedPreferences preference;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    public PreferenceManager(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    preference = context.getSharedPreferences(UNICEF_PREFERENCE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = preference.edit();
}
```

I  was able to fix this by moving everything in the constructor as so

```
public class PreferenceManager {
        Context context;
        String UNICEF_PREFERENCE = "UNICEF_Preference";
        SharedPreferences preference;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    
    
        public PreferenceManager(Context context){
            this.context=context;
            preference = context.getSharedPreferences(UNICEF_PREFERENCE,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = preference.edit();
        }
    
        
    }
```